# IBM Watson Personality Insights Not returning json profile

Tags: watson, watson-personality-insights

If I follow the instructions at this website, the first two (profile.txt and profile.json) should return a .json profile object. Instead I am just getting an output of raw numbers. This was working a few weeks ago so I'm unsure what has changed?

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/personality-insights/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out for whatever reason, it is returning the raw text values by default, NOT the structured JSON file as specified in the tutorial. An issue has been raised, however in the meantime you can simply add:

```
--header "Accept: application/json"
```

This will ensure you get the structured json file.